building openvpn3 library in another language
I'm trying to get a libary file generated using OpenVPN3 and I'm having difficulty building it with java. I changed CMakeLists.txt in the clients folder this way:
include(findcoredeps)
include(findswigdeps)

if (BUILD_SWIG_LIB)
    set_property(SOURCE ovpncli.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)
    if (NOT MSVC OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
        set_property(SOURCE ovpncli.i PROPERTY GENERATED_COMPILE_OPTIONS -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-sometimes-uninitialized -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unknown-warning-option)
    endif()

    swig_add_library(ovpnclilib
        TYPE SHARED
        LANGUAGE java
        SOURCES ovpncli.cpp ovpncli.i
        )

    set_property(TARGET ovpnclilib PROPERTY SWIG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CORE_DIR})

    add_core_dependencies(ovpnclilib)

 
    find_package(Java REQUIRED)
    find_package(JNI REQUIRED)

    target_link_libraries(ovpnclilib ${JNI_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(ovpnclilib PRIVATE ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

    set_target_properties(ovpnclilib PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "_ovpncli")
    set_target_properties(ovpnclilib PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

endif ()

the rest of the files remained unchanged.
When I'm trying to build lib in Visual Studio with -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON, I get the following errors:
PrepareForBuild:
  Structured output is enabled. The formatting of compiler diagnostics will reflect the error hierarchy. See https://ak
  a.ms/cpp/structured-output for more details.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild", 
as it was asked "AlwaysCreate".
  call with
"x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
  No update is required for all outputs.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" is deleted.
  call with
"x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Сборка проекта "C:\Users\dmitr\core\build\msvc\amd64\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" 
completed (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  creating dir "ovpnclilib.dir\Release\".
  Structured output is enabled. The formatting of compiler diagnostics will reflect the error hierarchy. See https://ak
  a.ms/cpp/structured-output for more details.
  creating dir "C:\Users\dmitr\core\build\msvc\amd64\client\Release\".
  creating dir  "ovpnclilib.dir\Release\ovpnclilib.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild", 
as it was asked "AlwaysCreate".
  call with
"x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
ComputeCustomBuildOutput:
  creating dir "C:\Users\dmitr\core\build\msvc\amd64\client\CMakeFiles\ovpnclilib.dir\".
CustomBuild:
  1>Swig compile ovpncli.i for java
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/dmitr/core/client/CMakeLists.txt
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /IC:\User
  s\dmitr\core\cmake\.. /I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\include" /I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\include\win32" /IC:\Us
  ers\dmitr\core\client /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /O2 /Ob2 /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D ASI
  O_STANDALONE /D USE_ASIO /D HAVE_LZ4 /D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 /D TAP_WIN_COMPONENT_ID=tap0901 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING
  S /D ASIO_DISABLE_LOCAL_SOCKETS /D USE_OPENSSL /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D ovpnclilib_EXPORTS /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:
  precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++17 /Fo"ovpnclilib.dir\Release\\" /Fd"ovpnclilib.dir\Release\vc143
  .pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TP /wd4200 /wd4146 /errorReport:queue  /external:I "C:/Users/dmitr/core/build/msvc/amd64/vcpk
  g_installed/x64-windows/include" /bigobj C:\Users\dmitr\core\build\msvc\amd64\client\CMakeFiles\ovpnclilib.dir\ovpncl
  iJAVA_wrap.cxx C:\Users\dmitr\core\client\ovpncli.cpp
  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33813 for x64
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  cl /c /IC:\Users\dmitr\core\cmake\.. /I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\include" /I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\include
  \win32" /IC:\Users\dmitr\core\client /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /O2 /Ob2 /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /
  D NDEBUG /D ASIO_STANDALONE /D USE_ASIO /D HAVE_LZ4 /D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 /D TAP_WIN_COMPONENT_ID=tap0901 /D _CRT_SE
  CURE_NO_WARNINGS /D ASIO_DISABLE_LOCAL_SOCKETS /D USE_OPENSSL /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D ovpnclilib_EXPORTS /EH
  sc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++17 /Fo"ovpnclilib.dir\Release\\" /Fd"ovpnclilib.di
  r\Release\vc143.pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TP /wd4200 /wd4146 /errorReport:queue  /external:I "C:/Users/dmitr/core/build/
  msvc/amd64/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include" /bigobj C:\Users\dmitr\core\build\msvc\amd64\client\CMakeFiles\ovpncl
  ilib.dir\ovpncliJAVA_wrap.cxx C:\Users\dmitr\core\client\ovpncli.cpp
  ovpncliJAVA_wrap.cxx
  ovpncli.cpp
  Generating Code...
Link:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPO
  RT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\dmitr\core\build\msvc\amd64\client\Release\_ovpncli.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO "..\vcpkg_in
  stalled\x64-windows\lib\lz4.lib" "..\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\lib\libssl.lib" fwpuclnt.lib iphlpapi.lib wininet.li
  b setupapi.lib rpcrt4.lib wtsapi32.lib "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\lib\jawt.lib" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\lib\
  jvm.lib" "..\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\lib\libcrypto.lib" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.li
  b ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false
  '" /manifest:embed /PDB:"C:/Users/dmitr/core/build/msvc/amd64/client/Release/_ovpncli.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:
  1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/dmitr/core/build/msvc/amd64/client/Release/_ovpncli.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /ma
  chine:x64 /DLL ovpnclilib.dir\Release\ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj
  ovpnclilib.dir\Release\ovpncli.obj
     Creating library C:/Users/dmitr/core/build/msvc/amd64/client/Release/_ovpncli.lib and object C:/Users/dmitr/core/b
  uild/msvc/amd64/client/Release/_ovpncli.exp

ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::connect_attach(void)" (?connect_attach@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@EEAAXXZ)

ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::connect_pre_run(void)" (?connect_pre_run@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@EEAAXXZ)

ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::connect_run(void)" (?connect_run@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@EEAAXXZ)

ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::connect_session_stop(void)" (?connect_session_stop@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@EEAAXXZ)

ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual class openvpn::Stop * __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::get_async_stop(void)" (?get_async_stop@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@EEAAPEAVStop@3@XZ)

There seem to be problems in the generated ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj file.
Does anyone know the correct way to compile it? Or the actions that need to do for the java build?
UPD output files from dumpbin inspection
/ALL command (get_async_stop(void) as example)
        ...
        SECTION HEADER #19C0
        .text$mn name
               0 physical address
               0 virtual address
               3 size of raw data
          1EEB55 file pointer to raw data (001EEB55 to 001EEB57)
               0 file pointer to relocation table
               0 file pointer to line numbers
               0 number of relocations
               0 number of line numbers
        60501020 flags
                 Code
                 COMDAT; sym= "protected: virtual class openvpn::Stop * __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::get_async_stop(void)" (?get_async_stop@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@MEAAPEAVStop@3@XZ)
                 16 byte align
                 Execute Read
        
        RAW DATA #19C0
          00000000: 33 C0 C3  
        ...
     00000148  ADDR64  00000000 00000000      5042  ?get_async_stop@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@MEAAPEAVStop@3@XZ (protected: virtual class openvpn::Stop * __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::get_async_stop(void))
        ...
    5042 00000000 SECT19C0 notype ()    External   | ? get_async_stop@OpenVPNClient@ClientAPI@openvpn@@MEAAPEAVStop@3@XZ (protected: virtual class openvpn::Stop * __cdecl openvpn::ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient::get_async_stop(void))

the rest of the error methods wrote like this.
methods mentions are also contained in the ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj dump file

Add set(VERBOSE 1) to the CMake script so we see the full linker commandline. Also use dumpobj  to check the contents of all obj files involved.

I used CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON for build. see if this might be useful to you. VERBOSE  didn't work

Check with dumpbin which symbols are defined in ovpnclilib.dir\Release\ovpncli.obj, look for the ones marked as missing by your compiler

all methods are mentioned in both ovpncli.obj and ovpncliJAVA_wrap.obj dump files. I don't quite understand how to work with them. Let me know if you need additional information
